# Display profile using current user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Text(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email!),
),
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Text(
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName ?? 'No Name' // I can't display the current username in my firebase
  ),
),
```

I can't display username of current user in order to update profile purposes.How to use uid current user please help me im stucked now :(

Comment: When creating  a user did you save their display name?

Comment: yes, i did. but can you help me how to use current user uid in order to display and update the profile user?

Comment: do share how you add the display name

Comment: i deleted already cause i messed up the coding . sorry :(

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: without seeing how you add your users difficult to tell.